# Is Blender smarter than final cut pro?

Tags: video-editor, final-cut-pro, blender

I currently running one photo studio in my hometown. I want to introduced new future in my business. So, i would like to start video editing on my biz. i ask to my friends circle "Which application is smart for video editing?". They suggest final cut pro, primer and scene cut pro like this. The Linux users suggest to blender is nice one. am also Linux user and know little bit about blender. My question is, blender is professionally good for video editing field? what is the different between blender and final cut pro? of course i know well blender is open source others are premium. I want know more other information about quality, support, run time and etc... Please clear my doubts. I was confused to choose my application.

-Thanks

Comment: at a glance, FCP/X is a NLE platform and is designed for editing, Blender is a animation tool for producing 3D/2D elements etc, it can do some editing but I wouldnt even think about it to be honest (in my opinion). if you want free Blackmagic do a nice NLE now or Adobe Premier part of Adobe CC

Comment: Oh... thank you so much @adam. now i understand about blender...

Comment: Do you know about [http://cinelerra.org/2015/] cinelerra

Comment: @AdamMannPro Fortunately, this website is not opinion based :)

Comment: @Dhivahar Please add a bit more context to the question to get a solid answer, what do you expect to edit, what cameras do you want to use to specify your requirements.

Comment: iKlsR at blender.stackexchange.com mentioned that following question could be interesting too: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/175/video-editor-for-windows-that-can-insert-images-or-audio-at-arbitrary-points

Comment: @poor Fair dues, about my opinion

Comment: @poor it means you are right to point out this is not opinion based

Comment: @poor I did try to change my post but I was to late after I re-read it, it does sound bad. Yes lets see if there is some more info from the OP

Comment: @Dhivahar can you give us a bit more info on what type of video work you shall be doing, music videos, corporate, short films, adverts, documentaries, TV work, etc will you be needing 3D elements, or just straight forward cut/slice etc, each NLE has pros and cons depending on the task at hand